# Struggling to compile android apps in Eclipse with a min-sdk that is smaller than the target-sdk

Tags: java, android, eclipse, compiler-errors, android-support-library

I'm struggling with "no resource found" issues whenever I set my min sdk levels to be smaller than the target+compile sdk levels. I've tried a lot of support library solutions to this problem but none of them have worked.

Here is one error in the eclipse console out of hundreds of these:

> SourceCode\AndroidExact\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191:
>   error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'

However, I can compile and run my android apps in two cases:

1. minSDK = targetSDK.
2. minSDK = (any api level) and targetSDK = (api level 21).

For these two cases, I am able to use the Eclipse GUI wizard to create and run an empty hello world android application project. I can also write a more complex app for these two cases.

But for cases where (minSDK < targetSDK and targetSDK != 21), my Android apps will not compile due to the "no resource error".

This solution[1] by reVerse on stackoverflow works. But there is a catch. It only works for target 21. I tried target 19, and it doesn't work. I need to be able to choose a target other than 21, for learning purposes and for device-specific apps.

I have also tried the following (and failed):

1. Installing JDK 7, and configuring for android workspace
2. Installing JDK 6, and configuring for android workspace

I think I will be able to make it work if I use JDK 7 with Eclipse Kepler, and that I am configuring my Eclipse wrong.

From Froyo to Lollipop I have the SDK Platform and Google API installed. I also installed the Android Support Repo, Android Support Library, Google Play Services, Google Play Repository, Google USB Driver, and the HAXM driver. I have uninstalled and reinstalled these packages just in case they may have been unintentionally deleted outside the sdk manager.

I am using Windows 7, Eclipse Luna, JDK 8, and ADT 23.0.4.

Do you guys have any suggestions or solutions? **I will provide more specific details upon request, as I will do whatever it takes to make this work on Eclipse**.

Answer (score 1):

Jump on the Android Studio wagon.  It's now at version 1.  My advice is to create a new project in Android Studio then slowly one by one manually copy in your source files.  This will give you a lot of experience with the new ide and you won't have a single headache with the migration wizardry.  Besides that with android studio and gradle to use the support (v7) libraries requires one line in the gradle file.

Example this is all you need in the gradle file with android studio for a google map application and the support libraries where its two extra projects in eclipse.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21+"

}
```